# Photo matching software

Tags: software-recommendations, photo-identification

Can anyone suggest a free face matching app for use on a Windows 10 computer? I have a photo of my grandmother at the age of 20 and another photo that may be her at the age of perhaps 50. Alternatively, it may be her mother. What would be ideal would be to be given a percentage likelihood that this was either the same person or probably closely related.

Comment: For software recommendations I think the place to ask will be the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange but before asking there be sure to review their asking guidelines.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to do automated facial recognition?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9950/is-there-a-way-to-do-automated-facial-recognition/)

Comment: @HarryVervet That looks like a duplicate to me so I am voting to make it one.

Comment: Yes, it is because I was advised by the genealogical group to pose the question to the software group. That is always the problem when a question falls between two stools. Actually, being able to identify if a person appearing in two photos with a 30 year time span between them is the same person would be a huge boon to any of us researching our family history.