# Finding age of man from photo by comparison

Tags: photo-identification

I'm looking to find out when the photo on the right was taken, so I can identify this mans age.

I am trying to work out either by the suit or the style of photo a rough era, as well as by the appearance.

I am trying to determine if the man on the photo in the left is the same person as the one on the right. We know the left photo was taken in 1949.

Anyone able to pose some suggestions?[image: nono?]

Comment: I think your question may be a duplicate of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9950/19

Comment: Men's clothing is a poor indicator, men who rarely rare suits may use the same suit for decades.

Comment: Most family pictures would be color by the 1970s, so I think the right is 1960s or earlier.